# Removing share text from d3plus tooltip

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

How can I remove the share text that pops up in the tooltip of d3plus. I want the share button removed from the tooltip. Its quite meaningless to me, is there a way to remove it from the tooltip. Below is my existing code.

```
        new d3plus.Treemap()
        .select("#viz")
        .data(data)
        .groupBy("id")
        .on("click", function (d) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: d.id,
                message: "<table class='tooltip-table'>"
                    + "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Businesses</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpercategory + "</td></tr>"
                    + "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Sub Categories</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpersubcategory + "</td></tr>"
                    + "<tr><td class='title'> Revenue Generated</td><td class='data'>" + 'N' + parseFloat(d.value) + "</td></tr>"
                    + "</table>",

                callback: function (result) {
                    console.log('Error is: ' + result);
                }
            }).find('.modal-content').css({
                'background-color': '#212831',
                'color': 'white',
                'font-size': '1em',
                'margin-top': function () {
                    var w = $(window).height();
                    var b = $(".modal-dialog").height();
                    // should not be (w-h)/2
                    var h = (w - b) / 2;
                    return h + "px";
                }
            });
        })
        .tooltipConfig({
            body: function (d) {
                var table = "<table class='tooltip-table'>";
                table += "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Businesses</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpercategory + "</td></tr>";
                table += "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Sub Categories</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpersubcategory + "</td></tr>";
                table += "<tr><td class='title'> Revenue Generated</td><td class='data'>" + d.percent+'%'+ "</td></tr>";

                table += "</table>";
                return table;
            },
            footer: function (d) {
                return "<sub class='tooltip-footer'>d.id</sub>";
            },
            title: function (d) {
                var txt = d.id;
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                ;
            },

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `tbody` to the `tooltipConfig` like this:

```
.tooltipConfig({
    body: function (d) {
            var table = "<table class='tooltip-table'>";
            table += "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Businesses</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpercategory + "</td></tr>";
            table += "<tr><td class='title'> Number of Sub Categories</td><td class='data'>" + d.numberpersubcategory + "</td></tr>";
            table += "<tr><td class='title'> Revenue Generated</td><td class='data'>" + d.percent+'%'+ "</td></tr>";

            table += "</table>";
            return table;
        },
    footer: function (d) {
        return "<sub class='tooltip-footer'>d.id</sub>";
    },
    tbody: function(d) {
        const table = [];
        return table;
    },
    title: function (d) {
        var txt = d.id;
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
})
```

The `tbody` method allows you to overwrite the default tooltip config of d3plus.
You can also use the `tbody` method to build tooltips more easily. In your case you can set `tbody` like this:

```
.tooltipConfig({
    footer: function (d) {
        return "<sub class='tooltip-footer'>d.id</sub>";
    },
    tbody: function(d) {
        const table = [
            ["Number of Businesses", d.numberpercategory],
            ["Number of Sub Categories", d.numberpersubcategory],
            ["Revenue Generated", `${d.percent}%`]
        ];
        return table;
    },
    title: function (d) {
        var txt = d.id;
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
})
```

That will overwrite the default tooltip config and build the same tooltip that you was using.